# Why does ffmpeg not fully document all VAAPI filter graph operations and are there more than what I've listed here

Tags: ffmpeg, opencl, vaapi

I've compiled `ffmpeg` from snapshot with `vaapi` enabled.

```
$ ffmpeg -hwaccels
Hardware acceleration methods:
vaapi
```

I was curious about the available filter graph operations that I could do using my GPU, and found this page of documentation

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-VAAPI-Video-Filters

This page shows a single filter, `tonemap_vaapi`. I thought it was odd that there would only be a single filter and that it would be `tonemap` instead of something like scaling..

So I ran this command

```
$ ffmpeg -filters | grep vaapi
 ... deinterlace_vaapi V->V       (null)
 ... denoise_vaapi     V->V       (null)
 ... procamp_vaapi     V->V       (null)
 ... scale_vaapi       V->V       (null)
 ... sharpness_vaapi   V->V       (null)
```

And it shows more filters that I don't find documented anywhere. Is there a reason why these aren't documented and where would I find out how use them? Furhter, I notice that `tonemap_vaapi` is **not** one of those available filters..

While we're on the subject, I was really hoping for some way to transpose a video using hardware acceleration. I do not see a `transpose_vaapi` filter but I did notice this thread https://patchwork.ffmpeg.org/project/ffmpeg/patch/20181225061644.6384-1-zachary.zhou@intel.com/, was this feature ever added to ffmpeg or why was it not? Is there any way to perform transposition with OpenCL? I don't see anything mentioning transposing under the OpenCL filters here  https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#OpenCL-Video-Filters

Thanks

EDIT -

I found the file `ffmpeg/libavfilter/allfilters.c` that lists many filters that are not documented.

https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/allfilters.c

This does how a `transpose_vaapi`

Answer (score 5):

All these filters were added over a long period of time with reviewers not always diligent on presence of documentation. Over the next few months, I hope to document them.

Both transpose VAAPI and OpenCL variants are available.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for replying and I hope you're able to find someone to help you with documentation.